# How messaging works in html page using php and mysqli?

Tags: php, sql, database

I am building a website where there's a messaging feature, this feature should work like how any normal messaging works. When clicking the msg link/button it shows us the list of persons(not the conversation yet) who we chat before entering to the personal msg(the conversation) from/to that particular person, my problem is that I get a duplicate friend(another person username) when both of us are sending as I have two columns for username(person who logged in) and friend(whom I msg with).

I believe that my problem is a logic problem instead of the code but I might be wrong. I have tried using different kinds of logic but couldn't get what I want. I also believe that if I give the correct condition in the second 'if' inside while loop it might work. Check my table and code below:

```
Table chats:

username(fk)   friend    chats    
   a             b       Hi b
   b             a       Hi a
```

And my PHP and SQL code is:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT username, friend FROM chats WHERE username = '$username' OR friend = '$username'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {               
                    if($username == $row['friend'])
                    {
                         echo "<a href = 'chat.php?usernames=".$row['username']."'>".$row['username']."</a>";
                    }   

                    if($username == $row['username'])
                    {     
                         echo "<a href = 'chat.php?usernames=".$row['friend']."'>".$row['friend']."</a>";
                    }                       
                }
            }
```

In the above code, let's say I am 'a', what I get is: 'b' two times, instead of only one so there's two 'b', but what I want is only one 'b'. Suppose the second record is not there then I will get only one 'b' but once I get a reply from 'b' it will display 2 'b', meaning once there's two records of 'a' and 'b' like in the table above, 2 'b' will be displayed. It is also worth mentioning that since I am checking from 2 different columns the DISTINCT in the query will not work(I could have solved the problem if there's only 1 column instead of 2 by using distinct).Please check the problem in the image below. Thank You for your help.[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Nothing as of now, it is just an educational project so that will come later once my website finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle it with SQL or PHP.

a PHP example :

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "SELECT username, friend FROM chats WHERE username = '$username' OR friend = '$username'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$chat_list = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {    
        $user = ($username == $row['username'] ? $row["friend"] : $row['username']);
        if(!in_array($user, $chat_list) && $user != $username)
        {
            $chat_list[] = $user;
        }
    }
}
foreach($chat_list as $a_chat)
{
    echo "<a href = 'chat.php?usernames=".$a_chat."'>".$a_chat."</a>";
}
```

Comment: MasterkinG, I am getting my own username i.e 'a' instead of 'b' but only once.

Comment: Thank you it works, but can I just ask - is it not possible with my method, I mean it is more simplier without array and for/foreach loop

Comment: NP, use `GROUP by`.